# AWS code commit: cannot git clone a new repo, error 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, git

### Short version

I cannot clone an AWS Code Commit using git and ssh.
I get a 403 [unauthorized] error

### Long version

> Feel free to ask to more details if needed

I have a specific IAM user named `aws_cli_user`

this user has the policy `AWSCodeCommitFullAccess`

I logged in using AWS cli using this user

I succesfully created a new repository

Then I logged in web console as IAM user

entered code commit

entered into single repository

added my PC's ssh public key to the user credential panel about ssh public keys (in iam -> )

I'am using windows, so I modifed .ssh/config file adding (as per documentation)

```
# Account AWS IAM 'aws_cli_user'
# Per prove, private, di Mirko 
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
    User aws_cli_user
    IdentityFile 'c:\Users\Utente\.ssh\id_rsa'
```

But I still cannot clone

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/awsca-chapter1-repo
Cloning into 'awsca-chapter1-repo'...
aws_cli_user@git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

> NB: what should I use into .ssh/config file as `User`? The numerical id or the iam username?
> Anyway, both doesn't allow me to repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found !

The problem was in my .ssh/config file

As `User` I must SSH KEY ID
you can read it in IAM -> user -> credentials -> ssh keys